# Can I compile NodeJS server side Javascript to solidity?

Tags: javascript, ethereumjs

I wish to write smart contracts for the Ethereum blockchain but would like to use server side NodeJS Javascript. Is there anyway to compile this for the EVM?

I do realise that it may be expensive in gas fees to do this, but I just want to know if it is possible

Comment: I don't know of any library that you could use to develop contracts in javascript. But you can develop using solidity and integrate the contract functions with your backend, just need to use web3.js or ethers.js to do it.

Comment: One of the missing piece is the translator from javascript to evm, the other pices is rewriting the libraries required by node, and last but not least the npm packages used by the project. A big hurdle will be rewriting the node's network layer since the EVM doesn't have anything like network yet.